# PHP MongoDB insertion issue

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

having this weird issue while inserting to MongoDB using PHP. My insertion code is as follows :

```
$tyre = array("m" => '5', "i" => 'test.png');
$tyreCollection->insert(array($tyre),array('safe'=>true));
```

After insertion, I see the following in my DB :

```
{'_id' : ObjectId("856876876786867"),"0":{"m":'5','i':'test.png'}}
```

Why does my new array have a key of 0 ? I am expecting :

```
{'_id' : ObjectId("856876876786867"),"m":'5','i':'test.png'}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: not **array($tyre)** but only **$tyre**, at the momemnt You are inserting **array(array(...))**

Comment: damm me ! Thanks a ton  Bartosz :) Can you add this into your 'Answers' section so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert only **$tyre** instead of **array($tyre)**

```
$tyreCollection->insert($tyre,array('safe'=>true));
```

Also always remember to dump variables with **var_dump** or **print_r**